# Electrum wallet is showing not enough fund

Tags: e-wallet

My electrum wallet presently have 0.0047BTC. i'm trying to send 0.001btc to another wallet but it says not enough fund. Any limitations i need to know?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because of transaction fees. Go to tools > preferences > fees tab and check edit fees manually and set "propose replace by fee" to "always". Now on the send tab you'll be able to set fees manually. Note that if you set a fee that is too low and your transaction doesn't confirm you can right click on it on the history tab and choose increase fee to bump the fee higher.